# Induction Proof: Define the sequence $ \ \ T_1, T_2, T_3,...\ \ $ by $\ \ T_1=T_2=T_3=1 \ \ $ and $ \ \ T_{k+1}= T_{k}+T_{k-1}+T_{k-2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, solution-verification

I would appreciate if someone could comment my solution of the task below:

Define the sequence $ \ \ T_1, T_2, T_3,...\ \ $ by $\ \ T_1=T_2=T_3=1 \ \ $ and $ \ \ T_{k+1}= T_{k}+T_{k-1}+T_{k-2}$.

Prove that
$\ \ T_{k}≤2^k\ \ $for all $k=1, 2, 3, ...$

The first few numbers are 
$$LHS =T_1=1≤2^1=2= RHS$$
$$T_2=1≤2^2=4$$
$$T_3=1≤2^3=8$$ $$T_4=3≤2^4=16$$  $$T_5=5≤2^5=32$$

Base case

When $k=1$ we have that $\ \ LHS=T_{1}=1≤2^1=2=RHS\ \ $ the proposition $P(1)$ is true. When $k=2$ we have that $\ \ LHS=T_{2}=1≤2^2=4=RHS\ \ $ the proposition $P(2)$ is true. When $k=3$ we have that $\ \ LHS=T_{3}=1≤2^3=8=RHS\ \ $ the proposition $P(3)$ is true.

Induction step

Let the integer $n≥3$ be given and assume that the propositon $P(k)$ is true for $k=n$ and for $k=n-1$ and for $k=n-2$. Then

$$ T_{n+1}=T_{n}+T_{n-1}+T_{n-2} $$
$$ \ \ \ \ \ ≤2^{n}+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2} $$
$$ \ \ \ \ \ =2^{n-2}(2^{2}+2+1) $$
$$ \ \ \ \ \ <2^{n-2}(2^{2}+2+2) $$
$$=2^{n-2}\cdot 2^{3}$$
$$=2^{n+1}.$$
$$ ∴ T_n≤2^{n}⟹T_{n+1}≤2^{n+1}.$$

Conclusion

By induction principle it follows that $T_n≤2^n$.

Now, to my question. Have I done this induction proof properly? Something missing? Something too much?? Any thing? What??

Comment: What you've done looks correct. However, I found using the relation symbols of $\lt, \le, =$ at the start & end of each line a bit distracting. Normally, you just use them on the left & don't repeat them on the right of the line above. Also, you state "$T_{n+1}≤2^{n+1}⟺T_n≤2^n$". Technically, you've only shown that using the relation on the right, plus the next $2$ smaller ones, you've shown the relation on the left. I don't think it's needed & personally would not use it.

Comment: Also, FYI, you can actually fairly easily determine what $T_n$ is in general. The recurrence relation is an example of [Linear Recurrence Relations with Constant Coefficients](https://www.javatpoint.com/linear-recurrence-relations-with-constant-coefficients). You can use a certain technique of a characteristic equation, as described in that link, to directly determine the solution of even considerably more complicated such equations.

Comment: Echoing another comment, what you have shown is that $T_n≤2^n.$ implies $T_{n+1}≤2^{n+1}$ and that is all you need for the induction. The implication does **not** go the other way.

Comment: @John Omielan & Somos: Thanks alot for Your comments and for the link. I've edited my post and I realise the implication. Really helpful. /Pablo

Comment: This looks correct. Note that is not standard induction (which shows that $p(n)$ implies $p(n+1)$) but strong induction (which goes from more than one $m < n+1$ to imply $p(n)$). Since this uses a fixed number of previous $m$ (instead of all previous $m$), I like to call this moderately strong induction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general result.

If
$t_{n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^m a_kt_{n-k}
$
if,
for some $c>0, r > 0$
and some $n_0 > m$,
we have
$|t_{n_0-k}|
\le cr^{n_0-k}
$
for $k = 0$ to $m$,
and
$r^{m+1}
\ge \sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|r^{m-k}
$

then,
for all $n > n_0$,
$|t_{n}|
\le cr^n
$.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
|t_{n+1}|
&=|\sum_{k=0}^m a_kt_{n-k}|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^m |a_kt_{n-k}|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|\,|t_{n-k}|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|\,cr^{n-k}\\
&= c\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|r^{n-k}\\
&= cr^{n-m}\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|r^{m-k}\\
&\le cr^{n-m}r^{m+1}\\
&= cr^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

In this case,
$m=2, a_{0, 1, 2} = 1, 1, 1$
so we want
$r^3
\ge r^2+r+1$
and this is true for
$r = 2$.

The polynomials
$r^m
-\sum_{k=0}^m a_kr^{m-k}
$
and
$r^m
-\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|r^{m-k}
$
are known as the
characteristic polynomials
of the recurrence
(usually the form
without absolute values
is used).

Look it up.